# Add values of objects fields in array and calculate average

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an object UserScore. It has field called score that is an number.
I am keeping all userscores in userScores variable and overallScore for average of scores.

```
public userScores: any = [];
public overallScore : number = 0;
```

I tried so far something like this:

```
   sumRatingValues(): void{
    let i = 0;
    this.userScores.forEach((score: any) => {
      this.overallScore += score.score;
      i++;
      console.log(this.overallScore);
    });
    this.overallScore / i;
  }
```

Then I am using this method in ngOnInit.

But it doesn't print to conole log anything and overallScore value is 0.

**EDIT**
How I fetch data:

```
getRating(){
    this.route.params
    .subscribe((params: Params) => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.sharedService.getRecipesScoresForRecipe(id).subscribe(scores =>{
        this.userScores = scores;
        console.log(this.userScores)
      })
  });
  }
```

console.log prints out properly objects with their fields and value
[image]
And my ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
    this.getRating();
    this.sumRatingValues();
}
```

Little testing on front:

```
<div class="class" *ngFor="let user of userScores">{{user.score}} - {{overallScore}}</div>
```

This is how it look like:
[image: result]

Comment: Are you sure userScores is filled with data before sumRatingValues is executed?

Comment: Yes, double checked with console.log method that fills userScores

Comment: I think it would be usefull you to share the complete ngOnInit method

Comment: Edited main post

Comment: if getRating is requesting some endpoint, you would need to use async/await to preserve the execution order

Comment: try defining userScores as `public userScores: any = [{score: 1}];` you will see this result on your logs for sure

Comment: Welcome to the asynchronous world, you need to call the function inside subscribe, so that you are sure to have the values! :)

Comment: Call this.sumRatingValues(); inside subscribe after assigning this.userScores = scores;

Comment: @AT82 thank you, this is what I needed :)